# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: centos, mysql, ssh, password

I've changed the password for admin user of mysql in phpmyadmin and now I can't access neither my Plesk panel and neither mysql via ssh. The error it triggers is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Abstract.php:144)
```

If I enter skip-grant-tables in my.cnf, I can access Plesk, phpmyadmin and mysql via ssh, but it doesn't allow me to change password.

How can I do to regain normal access to the Plesk panel?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset or recover admin account password for MySQL?](http://serverfault.com/questions/4309/how-to-reset-or-recover-admin-account-password-for-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use --skip-grant-tables than you can't change password with set Password = PASSWORD('string'), but you can do

```
UPDATE mysql.user set Password = <HASHED_STRING> where User = <ADMIN_USER> AND Host = 'localhost';
```

You can create hashed string with following command

```
select PASSWORD('test');
+-------------------------------------------+ 
| PASSWORD('test')                          |
+-------------------------------------------+
| *94BDCEBE19083CE2A1F959FD02F964C7AF4CFC29 |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: This works but I can't understand which password choose to make it work again

Comment: use any password to get access to mysql via ssh. I can't really tell about plesk panel.

Comment: Yes, for MySQL it's Ok, but plesk still doesn't work

Comment: Mb this link will help.
kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1710/How+can+I+change+my+Plesk+admin+password%3F#dv

Comment: Ok, solved for plesk using http://KB.odin.com/112492

Answer (score -1):

This is frequently asked question that already has an answer.

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/442/Resetting_a_forgotten_MySQL_root_password