# How to resolve "fail to connect to MySQL Server at localhost:3306 with user root"?

Tags: mysql, firewall

I have tried over and over to connect to the local server using MySQL Workbench 6.3 on my computer using the following parameters, but it won't let me connect. Do you think it is a firewall issue?

Here are my parameters:

```
hostname: localhost
port: 3306
username: root
password: [not_really]
```

[Here is the picture of my problem for anyone's viewing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0UMw.jpg)

Comment: check whether your mysql service is running properly and listening to 3306 port.

Comment: How do you listen to port 3306

Comment: do "telnet localhost 3306" or check in mysql logs.

Comment: I have tried to do that but it says that it can't find telnet on my system or rather it doesn't exist.

Comment: in windows by default telnet cmd not be there, so has to use putty or other party tools. But check in logs, or restart the mysql service once.

Comment: You mean restart MySQL from windows "services.msc" ?

Comment: yup, from there you can findout, the service is up or not.

Comment: Every time I do that it really doesn't help me. I know it's running but I want to be able to connect to it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: use this cmd "netstat -a -p TCP |findstr  3306" from cmd, check mysql listening.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that the MySQL listen on port 3306 `netstat -lnp | grep 3306` on server. Otherwise, check the configuration directive `bind-address`
2. Check that the MySQL accessible from you webserver `telnet <mysql host> 3306` ( - as in your web application configuration). Otherwise, check firewall rules. Note. telnet by default is not installed in Window, and may be missing in Linux then this component must be installed manually.
3. If the first test is successful, you will probably need to [reset a user's password in MySQL](https://serverfault.com/questions/4309/how-to-reset-or-recover-admin-account-password-for-mysql) and/or reconfigure which hosts are allowed to connect to it.

*Use root account for the web application with a database - a very bad idea!*

Comment: Slipper are you saying that I shouldn't have chosen root as the default username, and actually specified a username. Do you think I will have to uninstall the program and then install it again?

Comment: No reinstallation of the program it does not need, it is sufficient to change the settings. But it's just a comment, **it's not your main problem**, it should work with the root account too. just not recommended to do so for security reasons.

Comment: Where do I go from here

Comment: Do you think my firewall is blocking me from connecting to it?

Comment: Firewsall - one of the possibilities. Perform the checks series.